# How to catch current css translate() position in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, transform, translate

I would like to animate element on the screen by arrows. It should change the direction immediately while translation. So if element go to right and I press down arrow in half of the animation it should go straight down and stop to go right. But how can I catch current x position of the element. offsetLeft does not work. It is still the same origin position. Is it possible to catch current position of animated element? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call element.getBoundingClientRect()

```js
let circle = document.querySelector(".animate");
let style = window.getComputedStyle(circle);

setInterval(() => {
  let rect = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.left)
}, 1000)
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.animate {
  animation: animate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: translate(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(calc(100vw - 120px))
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate"> </div>
```

Not sure why code snippet renders the entire element in console.log, but in an actual script it would return only the value.